# IDEA can not format json file to pretty in mac

Tags: json, macos

my format key is good.because i can format java file.but i can not format json file.
example: this is json file

```json
{"code":0,"data":true, "name":"name"}
```

I want format this file, but i use format key is not can format json file. If i use format key in windows, i can format json file like to this example.

```json
{
  "code": 0,
  "data": true,
  "name": "name"
}
```

Comment: and i have try clean idea cache, but it is not valid

Comment: which IDE you use?and if it's VS code with format you use (prettier?)

Comment: I use Intellij IEDA, the version is 2020.3 published on 2020.12.1.